# Trying to do telemetrics on OpenStack using Ceilometer in Python

Tags: python, openstack, ceilometer

As a project I need to do some telemetrics with Ceilometer on OpenStack.
I was given an old piece of code as a reference how the newer version should look like.

Using what little knowledge of Python and OpenStack I have and spending hours on OpenStack documentation I wrote the following code:

```
import os
import datetime
import argparse
from os import environ as env
from ceilometerclient import client
from keystoneclient.v2_0 import client

from keystoneauth1.identity import v3
from keystoneauth1 import session
from glanceclient import Client


auth = v3.Password(user_domain_name=env['OS_USER_DOMAIN_NAME'],
                   username=env['OS_USERNAME'],
                    password=env['OS_PASSWORD'],
                    project_domain_id=env['OS_PROJECT_DOMAIN_ID'],
                    project_name=env['OS_PROJECT_NAME'],
                    auth_url=env['OS_AUTH_URL'])

sess = session.Session(auth=auth, verify='/usr/local/share/ca-certificates/openstack.crt')
keystone = client.Client(session = sess)

final_data = []


def list_all_projects():
    projects = {}
    projects = keystone.projects.list()
    return projects



def get_datetime(midnight):
    dtime = datetime.datetime.now()
    if midnight is True:
        current_dtime = dtime.strftime('%d-%m-%YT00:00')
    else:
        current_dtime = dtime.strftime('%d-%m-%YT%H:%M')
    return current_dtime


timestamp_start = get_datetime(True)
timestamp_end = get_datetime(False)
projects = list_all_projects()


for project in projects:
    project_name = project['name']
    project_id = project['id']
    
    ceilometer_client = client.get_client("2", **ks_creds)
    
    query = [dict(field='project', op='eq', value=project_id),
             dict(field='source', op='eq', value='openstack')]
    resources = ceilometer_client.resources.list(q=query)
    
    for resource in resources:
        rid = resource.resource_id

        query = [dict(field='resource_id', op='eq', value=rid),
        dict(field='timestamp', op='gt', value=timestamp_start),
        dict(field='timestamp', op='lt', value=timestamp_end)]

        # average CPU usage
        cpu_util = []
        cpus = client.statistics.list(meter_name='cpu_util', q=query)
        cpu_util = cpus['avg']

        # average number of VCPUs
        vcpu_average = []
        vcpus = client.statistics.list(meter_name='vcpus', q=query)
        vcpu_average = vcpus['avg']

        # memory usage
        memory_usage = []
        memories = client.statistics.list(meter_name='memory.usage', q=query)

        memory_usage = memories['avg']

        # disc usage
        disk_root_average = []
        root_disk_size = client.statistics.list(
        meter_name='disk.root.size',q=query)
        disk_root_average = root_disk_size['avg']

        resource_data = resource['project_id']
        + ";" + project_name
        + ";" + resource['resource_id']
        + ";" + timestamp_start
        + ";" + timestamp_end
        + ";" + str(cpu_util)
        + ";" + str(vcpu_average)
        + ";" + str(memory_usage)
        + ";" + str(disk_root_average)
        + ";\n"
        final_data.append(resource_data)


parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='Script for statistics')
parser.add_argument('--fname', default="stats.txt", metavar='FILE', type=str, help='output file names')
args = parser.parse_args()
filename = args.fname

wfile = open(filename, 'a')
wfile.write(final_data)
wfile.close()
```

For some reason, when I try to run this code, my virtual machine running it says that projects is an unknown attribute.

What is a newer way of showing all projects in OpenStack?
Is there anything else wrong with the code?

Answer (score 0):

I think that the problem is that you are using the v2 client API rather than v3.  Change

```
from keystoneclient.v2_0 import client
```

to

```
from keystoneclient.v3 import client
```

In the v2 Keystone API, projects were called tenants.